# Can't use a typedef enum to store state information

Tags: xc16

> hi - I'm using the XC16 C compiler with a Microchip dsPIC33F CPU. I'm trying to use an enum to store the state of a device. I have accessors to get and set the device state. The state is (or should be) captured in a variable called "currentNodeState" which is declared with the following:
>   `

```
typedef enum NodeState currentNodeState;
```

I then use it in the set accessor with:

```
void SetNodeState(NodeState state)
{
  currentNodeState = state;
}
```

which results in the following compiler error:Node_IO.c:168:22: error: expected identifier or '(' before '=' token
any suggestions as to why the error message
Jim

Comment: what is the question? You can't store anything in typedef, enum or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define what values are legal for the enum.

Cplusplus has a good write up on enums (near the bottom of the page): http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/

Here's a modified example from my code:

```
typedef enum
{
    ADJUST_NONE,
    ADJUST_FINE,
    ADJUST_COARSE,
    ADJUST_INVALID
} adjustment_state_t;

adjustment_state_t ADJUSTER_StateUpdate(adjustment_state_t currentState,
                                        uint8_t thresholdViolation);
```

Valid inputs to the function are any of the values in the enum. ADJUST_NONE = 0, and each subsequent value is 1 higher than the last.  That makes ADJUST_INVALID = 3.